# Pass value of button to append, jquery, Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, append

In my Ruby on Rails project, I want to pass via a button the content of that button to a list.

This is my script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".btn2", function () {
        $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>"); #<-- Problem here
    });
  });
</script>
```

And this is my button:

```
<button class="btn2"><%= date %></button>
```

When I press the button "btn2", another `<li>Appended item</li>` gets listed to the ol-element. Now, I want that, instead of "Appended Item", the <%= date %>-value should be listed. For example:

```
<button class="btn2">10-11-2014</button>
```

Should add "10-11-2014" to the list.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', ".btn2", function () {
    var buttonContent = $(this).html();
    $("ol").append("<li>" + buttonContent + "</li>");
  });
});
```